# How to list corresponding column names for feature importance in logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, classification

How can I list the actual feature names (column names) for the feature importance, instead of the index number of the features?

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=2700, n_features=3, n_informative=5, n_redundant=5, 
random_state=1)

model = LogisticRegression()

model.fit(X, y)

importance = model.coef_[0]

for i,v in enumerate(importance):
    print('Feature: %0d, Score: %.5f' % (i,v))
```

The output:

```
Feature: 0, Score: -0.11124
Feature: 1, Score: -0.04292
Feature: 2, Score: 0.00561
```

Desired Output:

```
featurename1, Score: -0.11124
featurename2, Score: -0.04292
featurename3, Score: 0.00561
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29131/feature-names-in-logisticregression

Also make sure you post the sklearn version you are working with.